# 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, server

I am using Custom User Model for user registration and login functionality. User login is running correctly but when i am trying to register a user, it throws me following error 
[image]

In database, this user gets save but here it throws me error.

Here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render , render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

# Create your views here.

def invalid_login (request):
    return render_to_response('invalid_login.html')

def register_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                #return render_to_response('register_success.html')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_login/register_success')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_login/invalid')


    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html' ,args)


def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

This is my register.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your user model look like?

Comment: have you tried with wrong and right credentials both?

Comment: Yes i have tried for both wrong and right credentials. And this User model is standard custom User model which django framework provides